# gdb "static field value has been optimized out" for static members of class templates with non-type parameters

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11, gdb, clang

Consider this simplified C++11 code, which does nothing but wrap two static variables `A` and `B`:

```
template<typename T, T INITIAL_VALUE>
struct StaticValue { static T value; };

template<typename T, T INITIAL_VALUE> T
StaticValue<T, INITIAL_VALUE>::value { INITIAL_VALUE };

int main()
{
    using A = StaticValue< int* , nullptr >;
    using B = StaticValue< int  , 0 >;

    // reference (so code is generated) ...
    static volatile void* p = 0;
    p = &A::value;
    p = &B::value;

    return 0;
}
```

Compile this code **without** optimizations (i.e., `-O0`) in `gcc` **or** `clang`, then run it in `gdb` like so:

```
(gdb) break main

(gdb) run

(gdb) info types StaticValue
StaticValue<int*, 0u>;
StaticValue<int, 0>;

(gdb) print StaticValue<int*, 0u>::value
static field value has been optimized out

(gdb) print StaticValue<int, 0>::value
$1 = 0
```

Notice that when you try to print `StaticValue<int*, 0u>::value` gdb says the `static field value has been optimized out`, even though optimizations are disabled, and yet it has no problem printing the other static value `StaticValue<int, 0>::value`.

If you remove the `INITIAL_VALUE` non-type template parameter from the `StaticValue` class template, this problem goes away, and gdb has no trouble printing the static `value` field. This leads me to believe that the issue is specific to static fields of (instantiated) class templates with non-type template parameters of certain types.

**Can anyone shed some light on this?** Is it a bug in `gdb`? And if so, is there an easy way around it so I can debug these types of variables?

**Note:** I'm using `gdb` (7.6.1), `gcc` (4.8.2), `clang` (3.4), which are all the latest versions.

Comment: gcc has some optimization options enabled even at `-O0`, you can run `gcc -Q --help=optimizers -O0` to see which ones are enabled.

Comment: @GuyGreer: 1) The behavior is consistent whether you compile with `gcc` or `clang`, and 2) there is no problem with the `StaticValue<int  , 0>` case which only differs from the other case by type (`int` vs `int*`, which are both scalar types).

Comment: Fair enough, I guess I just meant that `-O0` doesn't mean compiling without optimizations.  Even so, my guess is that no code is emitted (so nothing to optimize away) until your static variable is actually used.

Comment: @GuyGreer: Did you even read the question?.. Look at case `A` then look at case `B`. They are used in the exact same way, as both are referenced in the lines with comment `reference so code is generated`, yet only **one** of them is printable in `gdb`. If one were optimized out by the compiler, as you've said twice now, then it would occur for **both**, not just one. And furthermore, the behavior is the same whether the code is compiled in `gcc` or `clang` so it appears to be a `gdb` issue.

Comment: There is no high road to understanding a problem like this.  Normally the rule is that gdb is at the compiler's mercy, but one cannot discount the possibility of a gdb bug.  The way out is to inspect the debuginfo to see if it is correct.

Comment: To see if it is a bug in `gdb` you could check if the compiler even generated the symbols for `A` and `B` by running `nm` on the executable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access the pointer version, I had to use `print 'StaticValue<int*, (int*)0>::value'`. Note that `info variables` also uses this name, so this seems to be some gdb inconsistency between type names and symbols:

```
(gdb) info variables StaticValue
All variables matching regular expression "StaticValue":

File t.cpp:
int *StaticValue<int*, (int*)0>::value;
int StaticValue<int, 0>::value;
```

Comment: The `// reference so code is generated` statements are there to force the compiler to generate symbols and storage (without it, `gcc` and `clang` both do dead-code-optimization, even with `-O0`, and there would be no types or variables for those symbols at all). Regardless, you **did** find the issue at hand: the symbols differ between the **types** and the **member variables** of those types, due to the non-type parameter. For example, `<int*, (int*)0>` vs `<int*, nullptr>`. I think this is a `gdb` bug, based on `nm` output, and that it occurs with `gcc` **and** `clang`.

Comment: One more thing: since I've accepted this as the answer, and others may see it, please remove the first paragraph since it is irrelevant to the actual issue and detracts from the answer you provided in the subsequent paragraphs that the issue involves type & variable symbols having inconsistent non-type parameter formats (and not whether the symbols are being generated). Thanks

Comment: My point in the first half was that just referencing them like that did not create the variables for me (they don't appear in `nm` output). To achieve that I had to involve them in actual computation, even at `-O0`. Admittedly, it isn't relevant for the problem.

Comment: Jester: I see the confusion here - In **clang** (my default compiler), those trivial references are sufficient for the variables to be generated, but that's not the case in **gcc**. I edited the question (just now) with a minor code revision so it works the same for both compilers. Since, however, this is irrelevant to the underlying problem, can you edit your answer to remove this point? I feel that it detracts from the answer for others who may stumble upon this question. If you just remove the first paragraph and first sentence of the 2nd paragraph, the answer will be perfect. Thank you.